# How to get the type for a value of a property in TS?

Tags: typescript

I have currently the following code which works, X is a union with all the types defined in MyType, I would like to know if TS has a better way, or an utility fn to get the same result.

```
type MyType = {
    name :string,
    age: 15
}

type X = MyType[keyof MyType] // string | number
```

Comment: `type Y = MyType["name"]; // string` I'm thinking of this, based on your question "get the type for a value of a property"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a predefined one. But you could write your own:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=25&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQHYEMBbaALgGdgAnAS1wHMAaLHfOiEqARgFYMBfDBlCQoANXwAbAK4QA8gDMAPPAB8UVPADaAawggA9vKjwAuoOHQAGurGSZCxXESQVQA)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, I have a related problem here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867058/how-to-return-a-union-from-the-fn
Could you please help me? Thanks