# How to return a union from the fn

Tags: typescript

I the following, X as union type `string | number` which is correct.
The `fn` instead has a return type `ValueOf<Person>`.
I would like to ask you:

- why a union like `string | number` is not returned?
- how to make sure the return the union based on the value of `ValueOf<Person>`?

Thanks

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type X = ValueOf<Person> // string | number >>> OK

const fn = (myValue: ValueOf<Person>): ValueOf<Person> => {
    return myValue
} // fn is ValueOf<Person>
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGn0OMcqIFdSAjBLgC+uXKEhQAasQA23CAHkAZgB4AKgD5MUNQG0A1hBDIlOgLoBuUeOgANbdLmLVcJGg2iAxmhpQl6LAAKUhBHeSow5xVXFFQNAEoI2XllaIRYrQwtPEIoeAhgbnh0EMjhUSA

Comment: [Please ask one primary question per post.](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366)  For Q1: `ValueOf<Person>` is an alias for `string | number`; they're the same type and behave the same way (e.g., //tsplay.dev/Nabb0m ). If you care about the *displayed type*, the exact answer for why has something to do with a PR merged for TS3.9 but I haven't found it yet.  For Q2: if you want the output of `fn()` to be more specific than `ValueOf<Person>` then you can make it *generic* like [this](//tsplay.dev/WzAALm).  Can you choose a primary question and then move the other one to a different post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an even more narrow type than just "any type in the union" by using a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with your function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-XNf3-QDJ2nUEwPgtio3gdDMNlJkmXwwigA)

```ts
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  favoriteNumbers: number[];
};

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

function identity <T extends ValueOf<Person>>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

const result1 = identity('hello'); // "hello"
result1.toUpperCase(); // Ok, but this would be an error if it were (string | number | number[])

const result2 = identity(10); // 10
result2.toFixed(3); // Ok, but this would be an error if it were (string | number | number[])

const result3 = identity([1, 5, 7]); // number[]
result3.reverse(); // Ok, but this would be an error if it were (string | number | number[])


// Some types which aren't assignable to ValueOf<Person>:

identity(false); /*
         ^^^^^
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueOf<Person>'.(2345) */

identity(['hello']); /*
          ^^^^^^^
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322) */
```